# TFS 2013 Team Build/WIX/ASP.NET MVC Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs, wix, wix3.8

I'm trying to design a WIX setup project that needs to harvest the output of an ASP.NET MVC Web site.

There are several problems.

1. Building the ASP.NET project does not output the same content as a web publish would.
2. So it seems that I need to harvest the output of the published web site, meaning it should be done in a temporary location.
3. It should work on team build continuous integration (and in Visual Studio).

Every sample I've found so far uses temporary directories and command line steps before building the setup project.

Am I wrong ?
Is there another solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to run those commands as part of your build so that you have that output to then package with WIX.